# How to write raw query in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

There is a query:

```
SELECT ST_DistanceSpheroid(geometry(location), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.854289 55.685333)'), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
        FROM users
```

How to pass parameter `37.854289 55.685333`?

Also I tried this:

```
$point = "37.854289 55.685333";
      return DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('ST_DistanceSpheroid(geometry(location), ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT(?)\'), \'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]\''), [$point])
            ->get();
```

I got this error:

```
 "message": "stripos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given",
```

My attempt bases accepted question:

```
$lon = 37.857397;
$lat = 55.685333;

return DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw(
        "(ST_DistanceSpheroid(
        geometry(location),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'),
        'SPHEROID[?, ?, ?]'
    )) as distance",
        [$lon, $lat, 'WGS 84', 6378137, 298.257223563]
    )->leftJoin('doctors', 'doctors.user_id', 'users.id')->orderBy('distance', 'ASC')->get();
```

I have got an error:

```
{
    "message": "PDO: SQLSTATE[XX000]: Internal error: 7 ОШИБКА:  SPHEROID parser - couldnt parse the spheroid\nLINE 4:             'SPHEROID[?, ?, ?]'\n                    ^ (SQL: select (ST_DistanceSpheroid(\n            geometry(location),\n            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.857397 55.685333)'),\n            'SPHEROID[WGS 84, 6378137, 298.257223563]'\n        )) as distance from \"users\" left join \"doctors\" on \"doctors\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" order by \"distance\" asc)"
}
```

The row query that works:

```
SELECT doctors.user_id, (ST_DistanceSpheroid(geometry(location), ST_GeomFromText('POINT(37.857397 55.690576)'), 'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]')
       ) as distance FROM users INNER JOIN doctors ON doctors.user_id = users.id ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. The `[$point]` parameter should be the second parameter of `DB::raw($query, $bindings)` but you added it as a second parameter to `select()`.

```php
// What you have
->select(DB::raw(...), [$point])
// correct syntax
->select(DB::raw(..., [$point]))
```

If you've got nothing else to put in your select clause, might as well use `selectRaw()`. It's the same as `select(DB::raw())`.

```php
DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw('ST_DistanceSpheroid(geometry(location), ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT(?)\'), \'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]\')', [$point])
```

Personally, I'd write the query like this:

```php
$query = DB::table('users')
    ->selectRaw(
        "ST_DistanceSpheroid(
            geometry(location),
            ST_GeomFromText('POINT(? ?)'),
            'SPHEROID[?, ?, ?]'
        )",
        [37.854289, 55.685333, 'WGS 84', 6378137, 298.257223563]
    )
    ->get();
```

Comment: Could you check my question again, please

Comment: The error suggests there is a problem with the syntax. Do you get any results if you query the database directly?

Comment: I have added full query in question